# Calculating Lyapunov exponent

Tags: asymptotics, dynamical-systems

The Lyapunov exponent can be used to describe the asymptotic growth rate of the norm of a product of random matrices acting on a specific vector $X$, and is defined as:

$$ \lambda = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \frac{1}{n}\log || A_n \cdots A_1 X||,$$

where $A_i$ are i.i.d. $d \times d$ matrices whose norms have finite expectation. Oseledet's multiplicative ergodic theorem states that the maximum number of distinct Lyapunov exponents is $d$.

My question is, can anyone help me find a general form for the $2$ Lyapunov exponents of a matrix:

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
a & b
\end{array}\right], $$

where $a$ and $b$ are real random variables with  $\mathbb{E}[\log a]<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[\log b]<\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notoriously, Lyapunov exponents of random matrices are seldom explicit. You are trying to determine the behaviour of the random sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_{n+1}=a_nx_n+b_n$, where $(a_n,b_n)$ is i.i.d. For some informations about these systems, see the survey "Iterated random functions" by Diaconis and Freedman (1999).

Comment: A factor $1/n$ is missing in the definition of $\lambda$ in your post. // Unrelated: you seem to believe there are $2$ Lyapunov exponents because the matrices are $2\times2$. Not so.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The edit has been made. I said the maximum number was $2$.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I am trying to determine the behavior of the random sequence that you mentioned. The system I'm considering is:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{n}\\
x_{n+1}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
a_{n} & b_{n}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{n-1}\\
x_{n}
\end{array}\right].
 $$

Thus, I am trying to determine the behavior of $x_{n+1} = a_n x_{n-1} + b_n x_n$. Sorry if this was unclear.